# conflicts on git pull brings uncommited remote changes

Tags: git, github, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

I'll phrase my question using an example.
Suppose Adam and Eve are working on master branch, both checked out on commit C1.
Adam creates commits A1, A2 and pushes them to origin.
Eve creates commit E1 which conflicts with A2.
Before pushing her changes, Eve has to update her local repo, so she runs git pull.
Eve now sees the conflicts caused by E1 and A2 (marked as "unmerged paths"), but when she runs "git status" she can also see changes which were made in A1 as "Changes to be commited".

After Eve fixes her conflicts, she commits both her changes and Adam's changes from A1, and pushes.
The changes from commit A1 will now appear under Eve's name in origin (Instead of Adam's).

Why does this happen? and how can I fix it?
Also note - This doesn't happen when there are no conflicts.

I know that using git pull --rebase avoids this problem altogether, and I understand the difference between regular pull and rebase pull, but I don't understand how it avoids this problem.

Thanks

Comment: _The changes from commit A1 will now appear under Eve's name in origin (Instead of Adam's)._  What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: Let me clarify,
Eve's commit will appear as a merge commit, containing both her changes and adam's changes (Specifically - A1)

Comment: When you do a git blame, are Adam's changes from A1 attributed to the merge commit or to A1?  I tried to reproduce the problem, but I'm seeing that the non-conflicting changes are still attributed to the original commit, not the merge commit.

Comment: You are right, I think I understand my error now. I was confused by the behavior of merge.

What still bothers me a little, is why are the changes introduced in A1 appear as "Changes to be committed" and are not already committed (since they did not create any conflict)

Comment: Well a merge commit needs to be a single commit, so the non-conflicting changes and conflicting changes need to be committed together.  That's why the non-conflicting changes are staged while conflicts are resolved.  I agree the wording "Changes to be committed" is a little confusing, but really, even for non-conflicting merges, changes from a branch B are committed/introduced when B is merged into A.  The important thing to realize is merge commits are special, and git is smart enough to know what changes originated from the merge commit (resolved conflicts) and the original commit.

Comment: How it's smart enough to know that, from a technical standpoint, I'm not sure.  Would need to dig deeper into it.

Comment: Thanks! appreciate your replies.